# How can i filter my object list with an array of Id's - Angular/TypeScript

Tags: javascript

i want to have following code filtered with an array.

```
MyArray = ['1','2,'3']

this.productlist = listComesFromASubscription.filter((product: Product) => product.productId === this.MyArray;
```

Can someone help me out ?
i want to have productlist only with the products with the Id's from the Array MyArray.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question, do you want to filter the productId which are inside your array?

Answer (score 1):

```
MyArray = ['1','2,'3']

this.productlist = listComesFromASubscription.filter((product: Product) => this.MyArray.includes(product.productId))
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.includes(). 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

```
this.productlist = listComesFromASubscription.filter((product: Product) => MyArray.includes(product.productId));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with MyArray.includes()

```
this.productlist = listComesFromASubscription.filter((product: Product) => this.MyArray.includes(product.productId))
```